# get a value from a serialized string

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

There is a form, and on submit, I convert it to a serialized string to in order to submit the form via ajax.

```
var data = $$.serialize();
```

Now there is an input field named 'title' and I want to get its value to show a message. So I am looking for a method to do just that. I've tried;

```
alert(data.name);
```

But found out it's not the method.

**UPDATE**

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wHBYK/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with your form? Or post the HTML here?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277655/1272540?

Comment: @Yann86: I'm afraid not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need jQuery at all. Just do this:

```
$('#frmEditTab').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = this.title; //get the input named "title" of the form
    alert(title.value); //alerts the value of that input
});
```

Comment: If you want, you can also use only Vanilla JS, no jQuery. It's just changing few lines of code