# How to get values from string and represent it as json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**i have this hidden fields with this values** i need to get values specially from **setting field**   *id="fields[0].settings"* *(value="{"x":"x"}")* pass it as json object

```
<div class="fieldProperties"> 
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].id" name="fields[0].id" value="null">
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].name" name="fields[0].name" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].type" name="fields[0].type" value="SingleChoice">
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].settings" name="fields[0].settings" value="{"en":{"label":"Single Line Text 1","value":"","description":"","Choice":"","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[0,0,0]}},"zh_CN":{"label":"单行文字输入 1","value":"","description":"","Choice":"ar","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[0,0,0]}},"_persistable":true,"required":true,"restriction":"no","styles":{"label":{"color":"rgb(0, 0, 0)","backgroundColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"},"value":{},"description":{"color":"777777","backgroundColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}}}">   
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].sequence" name="fields[0].sequence" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" id="fields[0].status" name="fields[0].status">
</div>
```

Comment: Already answered  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277655/how-to-convert-jquery-serialize-data-to-json-object

Comment: Is it OK if you pass `id` and `name` as `id`, `settings` or `id[]`, `settings[]` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to convert string to JSON object you should use the following JavaScript command

```
var myString = "put here the string you want to convert to JSON in correct format";
var myJSON = JSON.parse(myString);
```

in your case you can do the following:

```
var settingValue = document.getElementById("fields[0].settings");
var settingObject = JSON.parse(settingValue);
```

Hope my answer was helpfull.