# Push an array onto existing form data for an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to append/push an existing array of strings onto existing html form data.
Posting manually like this works fine:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitForm').submit(function (evt) {
        //prevent the browsers default function
        evt.preventDefault();
        //grab the form and wrap it with jQuery
        var $form = $(this);
        //if client side validation fails, don't do anything
        if (!$form.valid()) return;
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.prop('method'),
            url: $form.prop('action'),
            data: {
                'ListRFID': GetSelectedItems(), 
                'Printer': 'e38911b2-1a2d-e311-be86-c8f7334c3af0',
                'ExtraLine1': ''
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (response) {
                document.body.innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I do the following and replace AJAX's data with it, it does not work. It sends an undefined variable in lieu of ListRFID.

```
var temp = { 'ListRFID': GetSelectedItems() };
var data = $form.serializeArray();
data.push(temp);
//AJAX data: data,
```

The following almost works but sends the post data as ListRFID[]: instead of ListRFID:

```
data: $form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'ListRFID': GetSelectedItems() }),
```

Anyone know the proper Javascript methods to get this to work? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is merge the contents of two or more objects together.

So in your Ajax call data property would be:

```
data: $.extend( {}, $form.serializeArray(), { 'ListRFID': GetSelectedItems() } ),
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Opposite problem from before. Now it sends the params as
0:[object Object]
1:[object Object]
ListRFID:a797ad3e-7d2f-e311-be87-c8f7334c3af0
ListRFID:a797ad3e-7d2f-e311-be87-c8f7334c3af1

Comment: Still doing the same thing :(

Comment: You have a different problem. You want a data object with keys as the names and values as the values. You need to convert the `.serializeArray()` result, a list of objects into a single object. That is a different question entirely. That question has multiple answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277655/how-to-convert-jquery-serialize-data-to-json-object

Comment: Thank you for the help! Your array part works fine but my question also asked how to combine form data with an array. My form data is just a generic form. I solved this by looping through the list and pushing it to the serializeArray()

    `var data = $form.serializeArray();
            var items = GetSelectedItems();
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                data.push({ name: 'ListRFID', value: items[i] });
            }`

Then data: data,

Thanks a bunch!